# seek resources in design amplifier

Tags: amplifier, rf

I'm an electrical engineering student in my summer training. My adviser is busy, so my training is self-learning, I'm supposed to learn RF circuits, ADS, and finally, design an amplifier do some cool things.

To reach my trainee goal designing an amplifier in RF, can you **recommend sources**(slides/videos/book/Udemy-course) in amplifiers design?

Comment: This is a question that is more suited for chat

Comment: @Huisman As a beginner in RF, I'm lost in many books and sources and don't know how to start, so I was looking for a guide to help me and that's what Peter did. If you have a suggestion to rephrase the topic or ask better questions in my situation I'm willing to learn it, note I'm new to stack exchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bit tricky - ask a dozen RF engineers, and you'll probably get a dozen different answers.

I think the best "cookbook" resource I've personally encountered is [RF Circuit Design by Chris Bowick](https://www.elsevier.com/books/rf-circuit-design/bowick/978-0-7506-8518-4). I have the second edition, but if you can find a used first edition for cheaper, feel free to grab it. The second edition added two chapters that weren't written by the original author that are mostly useless and disconnected from the rest of the text.

If you don't have it already, you should get a copy of [Microwave Engineering by David Pozar](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Microwave+Engineering%2C+4th+Edition-p-9780470631553). The current version is the fourth edition, but I have the third edition and that has suited me just fine. It is a great general purpose theory textbook that provides a strong theoretical view of almost every major topic in RF engineering. It does not take a deep dive into any of them, but it provides an excellent reference for developing a strong understanding of fundamental theory. If you are looking for a cheap copy, there are international editions available from online booksellers like AbeBooks for 1/10th the price of the US edition.

I would recommend starting with designing a low noise amplifier (LNA) rather than a power amplifier (PA). LNAs operate in their linear region, so provided you bias the transistor correctly and stabilize it, there is not a whole lot that can go wrong. Also, since LNAs operate with relatively low quiescent current, you don't have to deal with thermal management.

If you are using ADS, Keysight has a [nice video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WAingaHfBMs) on power amplifier design. Many of the principles are also applicable to LNA design.

Whatever you design, I encourage you to actually build and test it to see how well your simulations match up with reality. RF test equipment is tremendously expensive (a half-decent starter Vector Network Analyzer that operates from DC to 6 GHz runs around $30k USD), so you will probably need to find a friendly professor willing to let you into his or her lab to do your tests. Make sure you ask plenty of questions when you go to use the equipment - like I said, it's quite expensive and things are easily broken. Most likely a prof or their lab tech will be happy to help out a keen student who's building an amplifier as a self-learning project.

Comment: thank you, I appreciate your help <3